# Trigger.IO Facebook hasAuthorised always fails on iOS causing the user to have to re-login every time

Tags: trigger.io

Every time the user open my app, I call forge.facebook.hasAuthorized to check if the user is already logged-in, and has authorized my app; if that is the case, I automatically log him/her into the app otherwise, I take him/her to a facebook login page.

The expected behaviour is that if the user has the Facebook app installed, and has already authorized my app,  forge.facebook.hasAuthorized will return true (as is the case on Android). For some reason forge.facebook.hasAuthorized always return false on iOS, resulting in the user having to login using Facebook every single time.

I started seeing this behaviour after expending the facebook permission I request the user to authorize.

This is clearly an unacceptable behaviour for apps, which results in a seginficnt decrease in user engagement. Anybody knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question just in case somebody made the same silly mistake.

I had trailing spaces if some of my permissions, for example "user_likes " instead of "user_likes". Turns out that for some reason this causes a really weird behaviour.